# Show that the given transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ is linear by showing it is a matrix transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$R$ rotates a vector $45^{\circ}$ counterclockwise about the origin.

So, I have a vector and its tail part begins at the origin. It is $45^{\circ}$ and will rotate to the left. I don't have any particular points like $(3,2)$, so I assume that my vector is going to $(x,y)$. While rotating, the $x$ value does not change and stays fixed at $0$. I notice that the $y$ will change though which is why I get $(0,y)$.

$R\left(\begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ y \end{matrix}\right)$

$e_1 = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right)$ and $e_2=\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right)$

$\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ y \end{matrix}\right) = 0\left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right) + y\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right)$

$=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ y \end{matrix}\right)$

So

$R\left(\begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix}\right) = A\left(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ y \end{matrix}\right)$

where

$A = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$

I don't think I did this correctly, so I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Did I answer your question?  If not, what part doesn't make sense to you so I can make it more clear?

Comment: Hello Bye_World. Thank you for your response. It was very helpful. I had to refer to my textbook which did have a formula similar to your answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to start with an arbitrary point in the plane $(x,y)$.  I think it might be easiest to do a polar transformation $$x \mapsto r\cos(t) \\ y \mapsto r\sin(t)$$ first though.  That way rotating counterclockwise by $45^\circ = \frac {\pi}{4} \text{ rad}$ is simply a matter of adding the angle to $t$.

So we'll "parametrize" your vector $(x,y)$ by $({x(t)}, {y(t)}) = ({r\cos(t)}, {r\sin(t)})$.  Then what the transformation $R$ does is $$\begin{align}R(x,y) &= (r\cos\left(t+\frac {\pi}{4}\right), r\sin\left(t+\frac {\pi}{4}\right)) \\ &= (r\cos(t)\cos\left(\frac {\pi}{4}\right)-r\sin(t)\sin\left(\frac {\pi}{4}\right), r\sin(t)\cos\left(\frac {\pi}{4}\right)+r\cos(t)\sin\left(\frac {\pi}4\right)) \\ &= \frac {\sqrt{2}}{2}(r\cos(t)-r\sin(t),r\sin(t)+r\cos(t)) \\ &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}[(x-y,x+y)]\end{align}$$

Now we can see which matrix corresponds to this transformation.  Forgetting about the $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ for a second, the matrix which transformation $(x,y)$ into $(x-y,x+y)$ is just $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ isn't it?

Thus, reinserting the factor of $\frac {\sqrt{2}}{2}$, we get $$\begin{align}R\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}2\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \\ &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}2\begin{bmatrix} x-y \\ x+y \end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: Good answer, but given how garbled the OP's original solution is I think this answer would benefit from a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @augurar Is there anything in particular you think I should elaborate on?

Comment: I just think you should aim your answer at a lower level of mathematical experience.  I tend to favor giving a route to the answer rather than giving the full solution for basic questions, this gives the user a chance to test their understanding and ask for further clarification if they don't get it.

Comment: It just seems like a big jump to go from "$R(x, y) = (0, y)$" to "Parametrize the vector" etc. etc.

Comment: All right.  Give me a few to try and explain some more of this.